# git python library with push and pull command supported

Tags: python, git, push, pull

Do you know a python library that implement also git command push and pull?

[pygit2](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/)

seems not support git push and pull command. Is there a complete python library for git?

Comment: Check out [GitPython](http://gitorious.org/projects/git-python) or [Dulwich](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/).

Answer (score 0):

A complete Python git solution is the following module:

[legit](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/legit/0.1.0)